# RedirectToAction or direct action call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As long as i am using MVC framework for redirect i have been using:

```
 return this.RedirectToAction("ActionName");
```

However I have recently "found" that i can call Action from other Action directly like this:

```
 return this.ActionMethod();
```

By my opinion. Calling action is far better then redirect to action, because it is more read-able(at least for me) and complex objects can be passed with parameter without the need for use Viewbag or similiar data container.

In theory, Actions from other controllers could be called as well if I create new instance of its controller before calling.

I havent seen anyone redirecting this way thats why I am asking.

Is this terribly wrong approach for some reason or is this safe to redirect this way?

> Edit

Lets have

```
public class Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {  
        if()
        {
             return this.RedirectToAction("Action2");
        }
        else
        {
             return this.Action2();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        return this.view()
    }
}
```

By my understanding both code in If/Else will return same html code or am I wrong?

Comment: `this.ActionMethod();` isn't a re-direct. Your just calling a method. So they do, different things. Is it safe, yes, your just calling a method. But these will return different HTTP codes to the browser

Comment: I have modified question with more thoughts.

Comment: Direct action method call doesn't set HTTP status code 302 response to browser which `RedirectToAction` normally does, and not triggering redirection. By returning action method name it returns standard HTTP status code 200 (successful method call).

Comment: @Liam Ah, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference in your code is that `return this.RedirectToAction("Action2");` returns [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) and **no HTML**. The 302 tells the browser to re-direct to "Action2". The **browser** will then call the Action2 url and then get the HTML for that.

So from the browsers point of view:

```
call action1 url -> server returns HTTP 302 -> call action2 url -> get action2 HTML
```

---

`return this.Action2();` just returns the HTML from Action2. It appears as Action1 in the url of the browser.

So from the browsers point of view:

```
call action1 url ->  get action2 HTML
```

Comment: I got it now. I thought it was server who redirect between actions until html code is generated and send to browser. My bad.

Comment: What's the point of RedirectToAction then? Seems like it has more steps to achieve the same thing as just calling the action method directly.

Comment: Well it's a re-direct. It's a pretty common thing to do. For example you might have a login action that logs in then redirects to the internal url or a unauthenticated url. It's useful if you retire pages but don't want to loose the Google ranking

Comment: The benefit is that the new content is served on a new URL. This could be benefial for search engine ranking but there are other things to consider. What if this URL returns different content depending on when it's called (as an example) and what if the user receiving this wants to bookmark this content. It's a different thing that does things differently so which one to chose depends on what results you want. Neither is "better" than the other